# How to make smoke particles using matterjs

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm creating a side-scrolling game using Matter.JS, in this game one of heros is made of fire, so he needs to get some smoke, but I dont know how to make particles floating in the air, how I can make a float body in Matter.JS?

I want something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-QhKcae-6E

Please see my codepen here: 
http://codepen.io/vanuatu/pen/VeQMpp

```
console.clear() 
//
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-container");

// Matter module aliases
var Engine          = Matter.Engine,
    World           = Matter.World,
    Body            = Matter.Body,
    Bodies          = Matter.Bodies,
    Events          = Matter.Events,
    Constraint      = Matter.Constraint,
    Composite       = Matter.Composite,
    Composites      = Matter.Composites,
    Bounds          = Matter.Bounds,
    Mouse           = Matter.Mouse,
    MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

// create a Matter.js engine
var engine = Engine.create(document.body, {
  enableSleeping: false, // def = false
  render: {
    options: {
      showAngleIndicator : true,
      wireframes         : true,
      showVelocity       : true,
      showCollisions     : true,
      enableSleeping     : true,
      hasBounds          : true
    }
  }
});


// add a mouse controlled constraint
var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine);
World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);

// create the ground the stack will sit on
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(200, 250, 1500, 10, { 
  isStatic: true 
});

// create the wrecking ball
var ball = Bodies.circle(260, 60, 20, { density: 1, frictionAir: 0.001});

// create the rope the ball will swing on
var ballRope = Constraint.create({
  pointA: { x: 340, y: 60 },
  bodyB: ball
});

// basket ball
var basketBall = Bodies.circle(60, 60, 20,  { restitution: 0.9 });

// bubble ball
var bubbleBall = Bodies.circle(120, 60, 40, { 
  //frictionAir: 1,
  density  : 1,
  slop     : 2,
  friction : 1
});

//
initialEngineBoundsMaxX = engine.render.bounds.max.x
initialEngineBoundsMaxY = engine.render.bounds.max.y
centerX = - 200
centerY = - 200

// 
var square = Bodies.rectangle(180, 60, 20, 20);

//
var counter = 0;
var infCounter = -1000;
Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function(event) {
  counter += 1;
  infCounter += 1;

  //
  hero = bubbleBall

  // Fallow Hero X
  engine.render.bounds.min.x = centerX + hero.bounds.min.x
  engine.render.bounds.max.x = centerX + hero.bounds.min.x + initialEngineBoundsMaxX

  // Fallow Hero Y
  engine.render.bounds.min.y = centerY + hero.bounds.min.y
  engine.render.bounds.max.y = centerY + hero.bounds.min.y + initialEngineBoundsMaxY

  //
  Mouse.setOffset(mouseConstraint.mouse, engine.render.bounds.min);


  // every 1.5 sec
  if (counter >= 60 * 1.5) {
    Body.setVelocity(basketBall, { x: 0, y: 10 });
    Body.setAngle(square, -Math.PI * 0.26);

    // reset counter
    counter = 0;
    scaleFactor = 1;
  }
});


//
Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'startdrag', function(event) {
  //console.log(event);
})

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, [ball, ballRope, basketBall, bubbleBall, square, ground]);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

//
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){ 
    speed = 10;
    switch(e.which){
      case 65:
        Body.setVelocity(hero, {x: -speed, y: 0})
        break;

      case 68:
        Body.setVelocity(hero, {x: speed, y: 0})
        break;

      case 87:
        Body.setVelocity(hero, {x: 0, y: -speed})
        break;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this question in oficial repository in github, and @liabru answers me:

> What you're looking for is a particle system. There's nothing
>   currently built in to the engine for this, it's more of something
>   you'd find in a game engine so it's a bit out of scope.
>
> You could build your own by to defining a particle object (position,
>   velocity, lifetime etc) and then use the engine update event to update
>   the particle positions, then render them to the same canvas as the
>   physics objects. The built in body type could be somewhat reusable for
>   this (don't add it to the world, instead create your own particle
>   world).

Comment: you can use PIXIjs as your rendering engine, and then there is also pixi-particles which you can make particles with, just another option